# Provider string setting in SSIS config file on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis-2008

I've inherited an SQL Server 2008 R2 environment running on Windows Server 2003.  I do not know if it was upgraded from SQL Server 2005 or if it was a freshly built out system.  Due to issues with not being able to virutalize the physical server, it was decided to build a new, identical environment on a virtual server an migrate the databases and such to the new virtual server.  We did decide to make one upgrade and that was to put Windows Server 2012 on the new server.  We kept the instance name and server name the same (these were modified after we took the old physical server offline).  I kept the file paths and folder names the same as well on the new server. I migrated the SSIS packages from the old server to the new server using the Export option in Integration Services (right click on the package>Export Package).  The packages were stored in MSDB on the old server.  I copied the config files from the old server to the new server and kept them in the same file location as they were stored on the old server.  Ok, so here's my problem.  When I started all of the SQL Agent jobs, several of the ones that used SSIS packages failed.  After researching the issue, I 
discovered it was due to the SQL provider string (Provider=SQLNCLI) was set to Provider=SQLNCLI.1, which is for SQL Server 2005.  Once I changed this to Provider=SQLNCLI10, all was good.  A caveat to this is that other packages that are using Provider=SQLNCLI.1 and are working just fine.  The question that is eating at me is this, why were these packages running successfully on the old server which was running the same version of SQL Server when SQLNCLI.1 is supposed to be a setting used in SQL 2005 AND why are some packages working successfully still using SQLNCLI.1 and other had to be changed??

Answer (score 0):

the execute of some packages depends by the structure of this file.
the are some task or some expression or some parameters that have been redefined in the new releases.